# unity player moves too fast even with speed 0.000000001f

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following script attached to my ball on a game:

```
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    //public GameObject packman;
    // Use this for initialization
    private Vector3 currentSpeed;
    void Start () {
        currentSpeed = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            currentSpeed.x = -(0.0001f);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            currentSpeed.x = 0.0001f;
        }
        else currentSpeed.x = 0;

        /*if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
        }*/

        //move packman
        this.transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed.x, Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed.y,
            Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed.z);
    }
}
```

Then I touch left or right arrow on the game, and the ball moves really fast to one direction and never stops even if I touch the other arrow.

Comment: I don't think I'm acceleratin anything, it's not +=, it is =

Comment: Also when you let go of the key it should set speed=0 and stop moving.. From the code given I can't see what's wrong. Maybe clean and rebuild the solution. Use the debugger to ensure the values of `currentSpeed.x`, `y`, `z`; maybe `y` or `z` is non-zero for some reason.

Comment: The script you show does not have the effect you describe. There must be something else to your setup which interferes with this script and/or causes the behaviour you see.

Comment: @Quantic I found it is because I added "Physics -> character controller" to the ball. Removing this component did the job. Why was character controller producing the described effect?

Comment: My apologies, you're right. For some reason I saw it as an increment. If that the case, I don't think making the `currentSpeed` variable class-level would be advisable, it should be local.

Comment: @DanielRocaLopez I dunno I don't actually know Unity heh. Googling around finds [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25096823/unity3d-character-continuously-moving-issue) which mentions setting up the animator. Some responses [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/522223/my-character-keeps-moving.html) also talk about the animator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found it is because I added "Physics -> character controller" to
>   the ball. Removing this component did the job. Why was character
>   controller producing the described effect? – Daniel Roca Lopez

It sounds like the Character Controller you had added accidentally, had pre-written values for how the Object behaved.

So on top of your MovePlayer script, you also got the Movement from CharacterController.

Answer (score 0):

use FixedUpdate() like this

```
    public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    //public GameObject packman;
    // Use this for initialization
    private Vector3 currentSpeed;
    void Start () {
        currentSpeed = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    // Update is called once every 1/60th second
    void FixedUpdate () {

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow)){
            currentSpeed.x = -(0.0001f);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            currentSpeed.x = 0.0001f;
        }
        else currentSpeed.x = 0;

        /*if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
        }*/

        //move packman
        this.transform.Translate(Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed.x, Time.deltaTime * 
        currentSpeed.y, Time.deltaTime * currentSpeed.z);
    }
}
```